# Can't start mariadb service with brew in mac

Tags: mysql, homebrew, mariadb

I am trying to start mariaDB in mac with brew services.

I run `brew services stop --all`

```
jenkins-lts none        
mariadb     none        
memcached   none        
mysql       none        
mysql@5.7   none        
postgresql  none        
rabbitmq    none        
redis       none        
unbound     none
```

If I try `brew services start mariadb`. I get:

==> Successfully started `mariadb` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mariadb)

but it's not:

```
jenkins-lts none                        
mariadb     stopped albert.montolioagua ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist
memcached   none                        
mysql       none                        
mysql@5.7   none                        
postgresql  none                        
rabbitmq    none                        
redis       none                        
unbound     none
```

Not sure how to debug this, who is stopping it. I removed mysql services, install everything again. If I have mysql service running, and try to start mariadb, I get following error:

```
brew services start mariadb
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /Users/albertmontolio/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist` exited with 5.
```

Comment: AlbertMunichMar Did you get this resolved?  It looks like I'm having the same problem, and can't get it started.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm seeing exactly the same issue.

Comment: I don't remember. I don't think it was something known, I just uninstall postgres and stuff and at some point it worked

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```bash
brew remove mariadb
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql 
rm /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf 
brew install mariadb
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.1.2/bin/mariadb-upgrade --force
brew service start mariadb
```

I relied on two clues:

- I used MySQL before and there were some `mysql` paths in the mariadb installation.
- `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.1.2/bin/mariadbd --general-log` logged that that the InnoDB plugin was failing to register.

So I thought of uninstalling and removing everything MySQL-related files manually, then I reinstalled. If that fails for you look for any additional MySQL remnants.